# Using python variable in shell data in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab which combine the shell script and python script such as

For example

```
a = "test"
print(a)
!cd /content/drive/MyDrive/test
```

First and second line is python and third line is shell.

Now I want to use pytho variable in shell such as

```
a = "test"
print(a)
!cd /content/drive/MyDrive/{a}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.05-IPython-And-Shell-Commands.ipynb#scrollTo=8owaIAgjHOG3

Comment: Running `cd` in a subprocess is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To use a variable inside a shell command with `!` you can wrap it using `{}`

Your example is correct

Comment: Wow , it works smoothly . thank you very much. I didn't find.